# PHP/MySQL reporting library

Tags: php, mysql, reporting

Is there a known good reporting library? Before I go making my own, I was wondering if anyone who has come up with a solution I can adapt to?  Basically, I have a bunch of MySQL queries that I need to "report" on.  So, my in-house solution would basically be a bunch of mysql queries that need to be run through a drop down or reporting style menu and they would run the queries requested and build a little report of whatever sql query that was run.  Is there something out there that already does THIS, or should I just build something in-house?

Comment: What sort of report are you expecting? Just a data table or graphs and visualisations of the data?

Comment: Litterally, a table that has statistics or a "total sum" of data.  For example, if I need to figure out how many total pages are in a certain category, I would want a table that lists each page in the category with its page name, URL, etc.  Simple stuff.  I'm not really looking into the whole data mining stuff or anything; this is REAL basic stuff.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430929/any-good-php-mysql-compatible-reporting-frameworks-out-there

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [phpreports](http://phpreports.sourceforge.net/). It sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

[Pentaho Reporting](http://reporting.pentaho.com/), [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports), or [Eclipse BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) can all work with MySQL. I haven't seen any PHP based reporting libraries out there. So, you can just set up one of those applications and have it communicate with your database to allow for reporting.

If you are just looking build table output from MySQL statments, try this example from [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx): http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/loading_data/array_data/default.php#PHPCode

Comment: Not sure this is what I'm wanting to do.  I don't need pretty graphs or anything.  I litterally need basically a MySQL wrapper that would allow me to input SQL statements and have it basically build a table output with certain columns and data - that's it.

Comment: @drewrockshard see the jqGrid example @Christopher Manning included. It seems to cover the functionality you are after I think. I have used http://www.datatables.net/ in the past for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [Windward Reports](http://www.windwardreports.com/). With Windward you design the reports in Microsoft Word, Excel, or PowerPoint - so no learning curve and you can design reports that Crystal, SSRS, etc. can't even dream about. (Disclaimier - I'm the CTO at Windward.)

We have a large number of customers who use MySql for the datasource. And we have a PHP wrapper to call our Java engine.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1):

If you want something simple but effective try my PHP MySQL Reporter Script -  https://jellyhound.co.uk/mysql-email-reports/ - it's extremely basic but very effective, I've had over 500 sales and pages of feedback and questions.

UPDATE: THIS IS NOW FREE

It is packaged as a simple way to generate MYSQL reports by email but is used as an effective report generator by a lot of my users.

It includes CSV and PDF attachments and can easily be scheduled using cron or any operating systems scheduling software.

Comment: A wee update is due out this week that will enable csv and pdf attachments of your reports.

Comment: do you have any documentation about tcpdf and youre software?

Comment: Hi @juanFernandoz - https://jellyhound.co.uk/mysql-email-reports/ and scroll down to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I use two reporting engines for converting SQL quires to reports, I think any of them could meet your needs :

[Smart Report maker](http://mysqlreports.com) : this one supports creating MySQL reports based on SQL quires , views, and tables

[MYDBR](http://mydbr.com/) : This one supports building reports based on stored procedures

Answer (score -2):

I was going to vote to close this as an exact duplicate of a question which has been asked many,many times here. But the previous answers are not great.

Christopher's answer mentions 4 good products. I'd also suggest looking at [Agata](http://agata.codigolivre.org.br/), [phplens](http://phplens.com/), [Crystal reports](http://crystalreports.com/).

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned MSAccess - it has a lot of nice functionality for developing reports, but, IME, managing the software is a major PITA, and there's little scope for scheduling / integration.

Comment: Again, read my original request; I don't need a data mining reporting system.  This would be the BASIC of basics of reporting.  I even hate to call it reporting, even though it is.  I basically am wanting to create a "report" system that will allow me to build reports from MySQL queries.